# Use of Universal link open jitsi video in my App of Meeting but it open only my App.not meetings

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, jitsi

Hi team I want to open jitsi link Video in my app. after clicking the the jitsi link Video which in getting from what'sup, iMessage in the iPhone . I am implemented Universal linking in iOS but its open the my App only not open meeting of the link.
Any One idea please Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask question clearly as it was really tough to understand your question.

please check your meeting url you have sent through whatsapp or iMessage. check whether the meeting room name is being passed or not.
and please post https://community.jitsi.org/ here to get more attention. Thanks

Comment: Hi I am facing when three member join the meeting then it's not show third member Vedio in meeting . I am used Jitsi Meet SDK in Swift

Comment: I haven't worked in swift but if 2 person meeting is working properly and when 3rd person joins it starts breaking then probably the problem is in your video bridge setting, as during 2 person meeting it is only p2p but 3 person call needs video bridge. You should keep an eye on console log of client and also the server logs specially vide-bridge's. and please3 post with those here or in jitsi community I posted.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nafiul Alam Fuji. I have already posted but not getting exact solutions.

Comment: Have you provided proper logs and clearly explained your problems? most of the time people ignores question if they don't understand them properly or necessary logs are not provided. you can track your problem by dividing it and checking parts of it whether it is working or not and then search for answers.